# Resharper 7.1 intellisense bug about usings namespaces

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2012, resharper

I have 
- windows 8
- visual studio 2012
- resharper 7.1

And I work with ASP .NET MVC 4.0 using .NET 4.5

So I have class "Navigator" in namespace Core.Helpers, and I use it in razor view
[image]

As you can see Resharper tells that using is redundant.

[image]

When I remove using Resharper does not show any error, but project build failed

Comment: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/RSRP

Comment: Apparently @ulrichb meant to say that the link was one to a ReSharper bug tracker and you should report this behavior there since this feels like a bug in ReSharper. This is indeed a best practice, and I kindly ask that you do so. I'll ping a dev who's in charge of MVC support to take a look. Thanks!